# I installed OBS from using .flatpakref but don't know where it is installed

Tags: software-installation, flatpak, obs-studio, desktop-apps

I downloaded the OBS Studio `.flatpakref` from the [official website's flathub link](https://obsproject.com/download#linux). I was able to run the `.flatpakref` and get everything installed fine, but I can't find where it downloaded, so I can't use it.

I went to *Show Applications* and searched for it, but it's not there.

I don't want to use the one from the Ubuntu Software Center because it wouldn't let me write videos to my hard drive.

Comment: sorry about being vague, ill edit the post but I went to the flathub from the official site, downloaded the .flatpakref and ran it. it seemed to have installed everything just fine when i ran it. what im looking for is a launcher or any way to actually use it

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: Turns out you may need to restart your computer after installing a Flatpak for it to show up. The app showed up when I restarted.

Comment: What I am about to say may not be related to flatpak apps but logging out and then back in works more often than not, no need to restart